# Java converter for CgBI images to RGBA?

Tags: java, ios, png

I have a need to be able to programmatically convert a PNG file that has been optimized for an iOS application and remove the optimizations.  A [number](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/iphone-optimized-pngs.html) [of](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/CgBI_file_format) [posts](http://peperzaken.nl/1326/iphone-optimized-png-reverse-script-in-php) reveal the mechanism for doing this, but I was hoping there was some Java code already out there for doing this before I go do this on my own.

**Does anyone know of a Java converter for CgBI images to RGBA?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got interested on the topic and made some research on the area. On one related page on PNG conversions I ended up to [a `jar` package type of converter](http://www.kylinworks.com/products/PNGConverter/PNGConverter.php) which may be something that you'd be pleased of. I suppose it to be some sort of Open Source solution, because the source was announced to be found from the same place.

Comment: For those who need a library version of that same converter: https://github.com/viphe/ipng-converter (a few bugs were also fixed).

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a command line C program that does the same. In addition to the other converters (I have yet to test the online one), mine can handle multiple IDAT chunks, Adam7 interlacing, and all row filter types -- the latter is necessary to de-multiply color pixels with their alpha. All of this leads to, AFAIK, the very same image that got fried.
See [my website](http://www.jongware.com/pngdefry.html) for the full C source code.

Comment: Just and FYI here, but CoreGraphics APIs on MacOSX can read iOS optimized PNG image files directly. So, you can just open the image and save it as a BMP to remove the encoding.